# How is the Wizarding World separated from the Muggle World?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

Are there any unofficial border lines separating the two worlds? This is excluding the Leaky Cauldron pub or platform 9 3/4 of course.

In the wizarding world they are living in the same locations as in the muggle world such as  Bristol, Kent, Romania and Bulgaria, yet in the muggle world those places are already occupied  by the muggles. So where are those places that exist in the wizarding world.

I apologise if this question is confusing.

Comment: [12 Grimmauld Place](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/12_Grimmauld_Place) was home to one of the most elitest magical families around, and was still located in the middle of a Muggle neighborhood in London. If there were official border lines, the Black family would have been far away from it.

Comment: Its magic. Really not much else to say.

Comment: Just check Apple Maps. I'm sure they are up to date.

Answer (score 5):

> How is the Wizarding World seperated from the Muggle World?

The International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy establishes that the Ministry of Magic must hide the presence of the magical community from unrelated parties (Muggles with no connection whatsoever).

This, however, doesn't mean that Wizards are isolated from the Muggle community. They just can't reveal the existence of the magical world.

Some families have lived in areas with Muggle presence. Most notably, the Black family in Grimmauld Place. Another example would be Privet Drive (the cat lady is a squib).

> Like in wizarding world they are living in the same states as in the
>   muggle world

Yes, nothing stops wizards from living among muggles.

> So where is those places that exist in the wizarding world.

Some of them are:

- Grimmauld Place : Black family
- Little Hangleton : The Gaunts (slightly away, I think, but close enough for Muggles to notice them)
- Privet Drive : The squib lady
- Shell Cottage : Bill and Fleur's place, supposedly outside/near of [Teignmouth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teignmouth).

---

And finally, remember that the Muggle prime minister has Wizard contacts. But who's gonna believe that guy?

Comment: Surely no one would know better than the Dark Lord himself how separate those filthy Muggles are from wizards!